# Firefox not updating timezone on change in system timezone

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I want to use browser time zone to present date times according to user's timezone. On browser start up Firefox gives accurate timezone, but if browser is open and I make change in system timezone then if I check time zone in my browser it will give the timezone on which browser was launched. It doesn't update timezone runtime. This issue only persist in Firefox, chrome is working fine.

Is there any way to get the updated system timezone without closing Firefox browser? I am using this command to fetch current timezone offset `-(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60)`

Comment: no, firefox doesn't monitor system changes like timezone change - most users don't change timezones while browsing a website, and by "most" I mean every single user, so, it's not really a problem when the browser is being used normally

Comment: Make sense,  but if somehow this happens how can I inform user about restart browser? I am just thinking about the case if some one travels and timezone gets update on destination. or user updates it intentionally.
or any workaround for this issue?

Comment: why would the user need to change their timezone in the first place? If the user chooses the wrong timezone ... how would you know in ANY browser? It's not an issue at all - people don't travel between timezones with a browser open very often - I'm sure your website is interesting, but not that interesting :D

Comment: LOL... have to put this comment in jira as reason not a bug ;) :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a (5 year old) bug in Firefox which has been reported but hasn't been fixed yet.

see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1348916

and

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1567862

(1567862 was closed as dup, but the reporter of the bug was in the exact situation that a commenter to OPs post said doesn't happen often).

I was bitten by this very bug today as well.

And unlike one of the bug reports, it seems to persist across a page reload/refresh. Browser or tab needs to be closed and reopened. Chrome and Edge do not have this issue.

Regardless of whether people travel across timezones with browser open or not, it's a bug and so it should be fixed. But it is low priority on Mozilla's list, so don't hold your breath waiting.